# Triggering item renderers on hover with Datagrids

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I've got a client who has a list of items on a Datagrid.  When the row is clicked, it sends the user to another page with details of that item.  The client wants the rows to act like HTML links, where the color is purple when the link has been previously visited and its normal color if the row hasnt been clicked in the past.

I've accomplished this with item renderers and SharedObjects.  The application loads the visited ids into an array on start and the item renderer colors the individual cells if that row had been visited.

The issue here is that the client also wants the text color in the rows to turn white when the user rolls over the row.  Because the item renderer sets the color, it doesnt respond to the default stylesheet for the datagrid.  I can make it turn white on rollover of an individual cell, but we need the whole row to do it.

Is there a way to trigger a function in all the item renderers in the row, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to know how to do this. You need to change the data in the dataprovider for the entire row, then let the item renderer handle it. I did a full example (with code) [here on my blog](http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2009/09/how-to-make-a-datagrid-row-change-on-hover). Hope this helps, Casp